# Python3 - How does one define an abstract subclass from an existing abstract class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I initially defined the following abstract class:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod    
class Primitive(ABC):
```

Now I want to create another abstract class that inherits from Primitive:

```
class InstrumentName(Primitive)
```

I need this class to be abstract since I ultimately want to create the following two concrete classes:

```
class CurrencyInstrumentName(InstrumentName)
class MetalInstrumentName(InstrumentName)
```

I have read the documentation and searched SO, but they mostly pertain to sublcassing concrete classes from abstract classes, or discussing how Python handles abstraction

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just subclass, you don't need to do anything special.

A class only becomes concrete when there are no more `abstractmethod` and `abstractproperty` objects left in the implementation.

Let's illustrate this:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod    
class Primitive(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

class InstrumentName(Primitive):
    def foo(self):
        return 'Foo implementation'
```

Here, `InstrumentName` is still abstract, because `bar` is left as an `abstractmethod`. You can't create an instance of that subclass:

```
>>> InstrumentName()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class InstrumentName with abstract methods bar
```

Subclasses can also add `@abstractmethod` or `@abstractproperty` methods as needed.

Under the hood, *all subclasses* inherit the `ABCMeta` metaclass that enforces this, and it simply checks if there are any `@abstractmethod` or `@abstractproperty` attributes left on the class.

Comment: So I should just ignore PyCharm's warnings that I've not provided concrete implementations for InstrumentName ?

Comment: @EbramShehata yes. PyCharm is trying to be helpful, and can’t *know* that you intentionally are creating a hierarchy of abstract base classes. But that’s a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do!

Comment: Would it have been possible to do that `abstractmethod` detection from the `type` metaclass? That way the `ABCMeta` metaclass wouldn’t have been required. (I am talking about language design.) In other words, what is the thing that `ABCMeta` does that cannot be done in `type`?

Comment: @Maggyero: of course, but that then adds a lot of implications to _all types_. `ABCMeta` also handles virtual subclass registration, it adds a small amount of overhead when subclassing (merging the `__abstractmethods__` sets of the base classes), etc. From a design perspective ABCs are a separate feature that requires opt-in. If `type` implemented this, you'd no longer be opting in.

Comment: Okay for the overhead. For the opt-in requirement (by opt-in I assume you mean a deliberate choice from the user—I am not a native English speaker), I thought that the intent of defining an abstract base class was already clear from the presence of abstract methods. It does not feel very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (don’t repeat yourself) to me, more like a WET (write everything twice) solution.

Answer (score 9):

As @MartijnPieters wrote, you don't need to do anything special for Python, but PyCharm will warn:

> Class InstrumentName must implement all abstract methods

One way to suppress that warning:

```py
import abc

class Primitive(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

# noinspection PyAbstractClass
class InstrumentName(Primitive):
    def is_tuba(self):
        return False
```

Another way:

```py
...

class InstrumentName(Primitive, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def is_tuba(self):
        return False
```

Comment: pylint will also complain. Your second suggestion works for both.